# c# HttpWebResponse response null instead of 504

Tags: c#

the catch is supposed to give me a 504 but for someone reason, I get a null on:

```
  response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
```

Below is my code:

```
var url = "http://www.go435345ogle.com";
HttpWebResponse response = null;
HttpStatusCode statusCode;
get http response
get status 
try
{
    // Creates an HttpWebRequest for the specified URL. 
    HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    //HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(keys.Value.Substring(0, keys.Key.Length - 1));
    // Sends the HttpWebRequest and waits for a response.

    response = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

}
catch (WebException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\r\nWebException Raised. The following error occured : {0}", e.Status);
    response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;

}
statusCode = response.StatusCode;
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
var sResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
// Console.WriteLine(sResponse);
Console.WriteLine("Response Code: " + (int)statusCode + " - " + statusCode.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour. Since domain `www.go435345ogle.com` doesn't exist, there is no server you could send request to, and therefore no response to receive. So `WebException.Response` simply returns null. Microsoft's [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webexception.response?view=netframework-4.7#System_Net_WebException_Response) clearly states, that `WebException.Response` returns:

> If a response is available from the Internet resource, a WebResponse
>   instance that contains the error response from an Internet resource;
>   **otherwise, null**.

Comment: possible to catch a net exception instead to grab the timeout?

Comment: @jeriley: Sorry, I don't understand - how is this related to timeout?